# Modify capitalisation and add numbers to mass lines of text

Tags: text, notepad++, text-editor, editing, modifier

Lets say I have hundreds and thousands of lines of text like this:

```
yes:nice
up:true
six:hello
nine:mouse
twenty:cat
```

I want it to be able to do this:

```
yes:Nice1
up:True1
six:Hello1
nine:Mouse1
twenty:Cat1
```

So each line has 1 side with text/numbers, and a colon (`:`) separating another side with more text/numbers.

Is there a way to mass modify the each lines to make the starting character after the colon (`:`) UPPERCASE?

Also I want to know how to add any number(s) on the end of every single line.

Basically I want to know how to change the capitalisation of a character after the colon and how to add any numbers I want to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^:]+:)(.)(.*)$`
- Replace with: `$1\U$2\E${3}1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
  ([^:]+:)      : group 1, every thing before the colon & the colon
  (.)           : group 2, 1 character
  (.*)          : group 3, every thing after the first character
$
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              : group 1
\U$2\E          : group 2, uppercase
${3}            : group 3
1               : the digit 1, or anything you want to append.
```

**Result for given example:**

```
yes:Nice1
up:True1
six:Hello1
nine:Mouse1
twenty:Cat1
```